# Ship and call a .exe from within a .jar

Tags: java, jar

I have a jUnit project that runs various selenium based tests. I also have a .exe file that does more UI tests involving other targets and technologies and I want to invoke them from within jUnit.

I believe it should be fine to pack the .exe files within the jar to not be dependent on environment variables (workdir).

ProcessBuilder seems to want an absolute path to something on the file system. So should I just copy the file(s) to /tmp/ or are there better approaches?